Make Typescript infer object type by its property
I would like to have a function that takes a list of sections and then renders them. Here's a simplified example:
enum SectionType {
  Image = 'image',
  Title = 'title',
}

type ImageSection = {
  type: SectionType.Image;
  image: string;
};

type TitleSection = {
  type: SectionType.Title;
  title: string;
};

type Section = ImageSection | TitleSection;

type SectionOfType<T> = Extract<Section, { type: T }>;

const SECTION_RENDERERS: {[T in SectionType]: (section: SectionOfType<T>) => string } = {
  [SectionType.Image]: (section) => section.image,
  [SectionType.Title]: (section) => section.title,
}

function renderUpsellSection(section: Section) {
  return SECTION_RENDERERS[section.type](section);
}

I'm getting linting error in the renderUpsellSection() function:

TS2345: Argument of type Section is not assignable to parameter of type never
The intersection ImageSection & TitleSection was reduced to never because property type has conflicting types in some constituents.
Type ImageSection is not assignable to type never

How can I make Typescript understand connection between SECTION_RENDERERS[section.type] and section?

The problem you're having is the lack of direct support for correlated unions as described in ms/TS#30581, and the supported approach is to refactor to generics as described in ms/TS#47109. For your example it looks like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz This works great, thank you

You can add a section type generic parameter to the function so TS could infer the current section type and use it for indexing SECTION_RENDERERS, otherwise the result of the indexing is never:
Playground
function renderUpsellSection<T extends SectionType>(section: SectionOfType<T>) {
  return SECTION_RENDERERS[section.type](section);
}



The project is using Typescript v 4.9.5, looks like it needs to be updated to at least v 5.4.5 for this to work

@MishoTektumanidze i always try to use the latest stable TS since TS is quite weak and new features make it less silly
